# How To Re-size Properly On A Mobile Phone's Broswer?

Tags: html, css

My site [ https://gatecybertech.com/more_info.html ] looks OK from a PC, but when viewed from an Android phone's browser, there are extra white space on the blue background sections, I know it's because the "Videos" section is sticking out, it won't re-size properly, my CSS looks like the following :

```
  #Keypad_Pins_Easily_Stolen { width: 5vw; height: auto; }
  #How_To_Steal_Passwords { width: 5vw; height: auto; }
  #How_Keylogger_Works { width: 5vw; height: auto; }
  ...
```

How to fix it so that the "Videos" section can have the same size as other sections and there will be no white space [ on the right side ] at the blue background sections ?

Comment: Your table is set to a definite width in the HTML. If you remove that, the white space should be gone. You'll need to do something about the text though because it gets crammed on smaller screens. If you can, using a CSS [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) or [grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) layout might be a better option for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jack, I fixed it, instead of "`<table width=1000 border=1>`", I now have "`<table width=100% border=1>`".

Answer (score 1):

I have a better solution for it. Use `@media` queries in CSS *or* you can also use Grid or Flexbox system in CSS. They are very effective and modern / supported solutions, and also you can learn a lot and practise by that way.